# Browser says 'reactComponent is not defined' in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs

I am following a react tutorial but I am stuck. I am trying to change the state of an element in the console. but when i type this

```
reactComponent.setState({
   isVisible:false
})
```

I get this error from chrome.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: reactComponent is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:1
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Here's my HTMl and JSX

```
<div id="app"></div>

    <script src="js/react-0.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/JSXTransformer-0.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        /**@jsx React.DOM*/

        //Main Element with JSX
        var MessageBoxJSX = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {
                    isVisible: true,
                    titleMessage: 'Hello, World'
                }
            },

            render: function() {

                var inlineStyles = {
                    display: this.state.isVisible ? 'block' : 'none'

                };

                return (
                    <div className = "container" style={inlineStyles}>
                        <h1>{this.state.titleMessage}</h1>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        })

        //Render JSX component
        React.renderComponent(
            <MessageBoxJSX/>,
            document.getElementById('app')
        )
    </script>
```

I am working with an older version of react but that's what the tutorial uses so I'm following it to understand react.

My question is how do i get the browser to change state without throwing that error?

Comment: Maybe you should try a newer React library first 0.13.3 or 0.14 beta

Comment: that's correct because `reactComponent` is not defined. try to do: `this.setState({})` instead

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass the name of the component, like you are doing in 
`reactComponent.setState({
   isVisible:false
})`

Instead you pass a reference to that component using `this` :

`this.setState({
   isVisible: false
 });`

Comment: So sorry for the late reply. But i tried what you suggested and still had the same error.

Comment: I tried it out but that didn't work. However I was able to change the isVisible state in the 'React' tab that appeared in the chrome dev tools next to the 'console' tab after installing the React [Devtools](http://fb.me/react-devtools)